# Parse input text file perform SQL query and results to a output text file

Tags: c#

I am fairly new to C# and I am trying to convert a old automated process on a mainframe to a console .NET C# application. I need to take a input text file parse it and use some of the values from the parse to perform a SQL query and then store the results in a output text file. I need to parse the input file by a line then do the query then write part of the results to a output file, then go to next line and repeat until end of input file.

I am having trouble getting it to work. I am not getting any errors just a blank output file. This is a automated, or will be once i get it to work and I think i don't need to worry about SQL injection.

I noticed I am getting a exception:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Data.dll

What does it mean? Something wrong with query?
I updated my code following advice from comments
This is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;


namespace MainframeAuto1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SqlConnection con;
            SqlDataReader reader;
            SqlDataAdapter da;
            //int counter = 0;

            //Below is the input file for program
            //C:\Users\csembry\Desktop\s0c119infile.txt

            try
            {
                int id;
                con = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.connectionStr);

                //Console.WriteLine("Test");
                int counter = 0;
                string line;
                //string oline;
                //Read the file and display it line by line.
                System.IO.StreamReader file;
                file = new System.IO.StreamReader("C:\\Users\\csembry\\Desktop\\SOC110infile.txt");
                System.IO.StreamWriter ofile;
                ofile = new System.IO.StreamWriter("C:\\Users\\csembry\\Desktop\\test.txt");

                //Default value for WWAGE_SSN 
                //Will be changed late
                string CCYYQ =   "20152";

                string sql = "SELECT WWAGE_SSN, WWAGE_CCYYQ, WWAGE_SER, WWAGE_EARNS, WWAGE_LNAME, WWAGE_FNAME FROM dbo.WWAGE WHERE WWAGE_CCYYQ = @Parameter1 and WWAGE_SSN = @Parameter2 order by WWAGE_SSN";

                //using (con = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.connectionStr)) 
                //command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Parameter", CCYYQ);

                while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    con.Open();
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);

                    //int len = line.Length;

                    //Below is the parsing of input file into string variables
                    line = line.Replace("     ", "");
                    string ssnline = line;
                    string fourdline = line;
                    string onedline = line;

                    string ssn = ssnline.Substring(0, 9);
                    string fourd = fourdline.Substring(9,4);
                    string oned = onedline.Substring(12,1);
                    string name = line.Substring(14);

                    // this is first query being executed
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Parameter1", CCYYQ);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Parameter2", ssn);

                  SqlDataReader doit = cmd.ExecuteReader();


                while (doit.Read())
                {
                    ofile.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}",doit[0]));
                }


                }

                con.Close();
                file.Close();
                ofile.Close();
                // Suspend the screen.
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is returned from this line: var qanswer = cmd.ExecuteReader(); ??

Comment: cmd.ExecuteReader() will return a SqlDataReader and cannot be converted to at string with Convert.ToString(..). You have to work on the SqlDataReader. Just look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9kcbe65k(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @njw I thought the results of the query.

Comment: @togocoder  I updated code following advice. I am closer but it still giving blank output file and I listed a exception I did not notice earlier."A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Data.dll"

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with returned SQL Server queries, you need to instruct the code what column you want to retrieve, and how to retrieve it. Your posted code only specifies the column, but not how to retrieve it.

Consider changing your `while` loop to the following:

```
            string strTemp = string.Empty;
            while (doit.Read())
            {
                strTemp = doit.GetString( doit.GetOrdinal( "WWAGE_SSN" ) );
                ofile.WriteLine( strTemp );
            }
```

In this change, `strTemp` will be loaded with a string of the reader's `WWAGE_SSN` column. This will work as long as the column `WWAGE_SSN` is a data type that is convertible to a string (ie, char[width], varchar[width]).
Afterward, the returned string value is fed to your output file stream.

By using the `GetOrdinal()` call, your code will no longer be vulnerable to having the selected column order being changed.

This code segment is debug friendly. You could combine this into more compact code, but being able to easily step through your code to see what it is doing is very helpful when you are trying to get the values out of a troublesome returned select.